# Find element with specific attribute in xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layout>
  <menu name="Employees" url="Employees.aspx" admin="0">
  </menu>
  <menu name="Projects" url="Projects.aspx" admin="1">
  </menu>
  <menu name="Cases" url="Cases.aspx" admin="1">
  </menu>
  <menu name="CaseView" url="CaseView.aspx" admin="1" hidden="1" parent="Projects">
  </menu>
  <menu name="Management" url="" admin="1">
    <item name="Groups" url="Groups.aspx" admin="1" parent="Management"/>
    <item name="Statuses" url="Statuses.aspx" admin="1"/>
  </menu>
</layout>
```

Here I have CaseView and Groups that both have a 'parent' attribute.

Currently I iterate like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> menus =
            doc.Element("layout").Elements();

            foreach (var menu in menus)
            {
                     string name = menu.Attribute("name").Value;
                string active = "";
                string url = menu.Attribute("url").Value;
                if(activePage == url)
                {
                    active = "class=\"active\"";
                }
                ...
```

What I want is:

```
        if(activePage == url || ActiveIsChildOf(name, activePage))
        {
            active = "class=\"active\"";
        }
```

Essentially this method needs to find if an element with activePage as its url attribute exists. If it does, see if it has a parent attribute; if it does, check if the parent == name.

Is there some way to find an element by attribute or something? 
ex:

```
XElement e = doc.GetByAttribute("url",activePage)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Linq to XML, you can use `Descendants` method - it returns all child elements, not just the direct children. After that, you can use LINQ to filter the results.

```
XDocument doc;
string activePage;
var activeMenu = doc.Descendants("menu")
     .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Attribute("url").Value == activePage);
```

You might need to check if `o.Attribute("url")` does not return `null` (it does when the attribute does not exist) if you cannot guarantee that the source XML does not have such attribute for all menu elements.

You can also skip the argument to `Descendants()` to check all elements - in your sample data that would allow you to check both menu and item elements. For example:

```
var activeMenu = doc.Descendants()
     .Where(o => o.Name == "menu" || o.Name == "item")
     .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Attribute("url").Value == activePage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If xpath is too cryptic, you can use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> hits =
        (from el in XMLDoc.root.Elements("item")
         where (string)el.Attribute("url") == activePage
         select el);
```

or like this:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(file);
XElement xele = xml.Elements("item").FirstOrDefault(e => ((string)e.Attribute("url")) == activePage);
if(null != xele ) 
{
    // do something with it
}
```

And you probably want it case-insensitive:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(file);
XElement xele = xml.Elements("item").FirstOrDefault(e => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals((string)e.Attribute("url") , activePage));
if(null != xele ) 
{
    // do something with it
}
```

If you want both menu and item, use this:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(file);
XElement xele = xml.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals((string)e.Attribute("url") , activePage));
if(null != xele ) 
{
    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: Niice didn't know this. To me LINQ and Lambdas are waaaaaay more cryptic than XPath but since he's using it in the example above I guess this is maybe an easier solution for him.

Comment: Will this return for ALL or only elements of 'item' I also have elements of 'menu'.

Comment: The second last one only finds the first element of type "item" with attribute url="activePage", the first one all elements of type "item" with attribute url="activePage", the last one the first element of whatever type with attribute activepage

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `xPath`. It's a query language for `XML`.

You can formulate something like this :

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("XmlFile.xml");

//Fetch your node here 
XmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(/layout/menu[@url='activepage'][1]);
```

It returns a set of node and the index 1 is to get the first node of the given set.

You can always use `xDoc.SelectNodes` if you want all the matching nodes.

---

Since you are using `LINQ` you can simply include `System.Xml.XPath` and select nodes with `XPathSelectElement` or `XPathSelectElements`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with XPath:

```
doc.SelectNodes("//*[@url='" + activePage + "']")
```

It will return **all** document items that have `activePage` as `url` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A case insensitive search example, converting xml to a dictionary:

```
Dim expandos = XDocument.Parse(Request("Xml")).Root.Elements.Select(
    Function(e)
        Dim expando As Object = New ExpandoObject,
            dic = e.Attributes.ToDictionary(Function(a) a.Name.LocalName, Function(a) a.Value,
                StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        expando.PedidoId = dic("PedidoId")
        expando.FichaTecnicaModeloId = dic("FichaTecnicaModeloId")
        expando.Comodo = dic("Comodo")
        expando.Cliente = dic("Cliente")
        Return expando
    End Function)
```